# NSClassForString for Swift classes with target name having space in it

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, runtime

As per document here: [Using Swift With Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH5-XID_57)
we need to have fully qualified name to get a class from `NSClassFromString()`

For e.g. if the target name is ABC and class name is XYZ we get the class by calling `NSClassFromString(ABC.XYZ)

However, I am not able to get the results when there is a space in the name of the target, i.e. when target name is something like `dummy target`. How do we get class in such scenario?

It is valid for a target name to have spaces, like shown in figure below
[image]

Comment: Class names can't have spaces in the name.

Comment: I'm talking about target name having spaces in them. Obviously classes cannot have space.

Comment: A target name can't have spaces either. You really need to update your question to clearly show what you code you actually have and what you really need to do.

Comment: Please see the image.

Comment: Please "read" the link I shared in my question.

Comment: It's better if your question stands on its own without the need to link elsewhere. Links go bad over time. Update your question with a relevant quote from the linked documentation.

Comment: @maddy - if you do not understand "target", I'm sorry, I cannot help you with more clarity.

Comment: The target name can contain spaces, but the *module name* cannot. You should find the module name in the build settings, I assume it is "SwiftDemo_copy" with an underscore.

Comment: @MartinR - that works - please write answer. I'll mark correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *fully qualified class name* is

```
 <product_module_name>.<class_name>
```

The target name can contain spaces (or other special characters), 
but the module name cannot, it must be a valid identifier. These two need not be identical.

Xcode derives a module name from the target name when a new target is
created.
If the target name is a valid module name then both will be equal by
default. Otherwise Xcode replaces invalid characters by an underscore.
The product module name can also be configured in the build settings.

Example:

- Target name: "My Target #2"
- Product module name: "My_Target__2"
- Class name: "MyClass"
- Fully qualified class name: "My_Target__2.MyClass"

  ```
  let myClass: AnyClass? = NSClassFromString("My_Target__2.MyClass")
  ```

Comment: I had the problem with a hyphen in my app name -> target... replacing it with an underline helped, thx